# Typescript loader not working for OpenAPI generated classes

Tags: typescript, code-generation, openapi, loader

I have generated a typescript-fetch client with OpenAPI and after I imported it in my application and tried to run it, I receive these erros:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (32:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|  * @interface Division
|  */
> export interface Division {
|     /**
|      *
```

I can't seem to find a solution to this. What could be causing it and could I fix it?